# Laravel, rendering google address api with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to render google api, this is very necessary if the customer select delivery not pick up so he must add his address by filling google address form, what Im facing now is just when including google form, then I have to add the script link, thats why im getting the error:
You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
what is the best solution for this issue?

googleform.blade:

```
  <input id="autocomplete" class="addressInput-textInput s-form-control input-overflow" onClick="this.select();" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" required=""/>

   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=0000&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" defer></script>
```

jquery:

```
$.ajax .....

success: function (data) {
            $('#update_order_status').html(data.update_order_status);
        }
    });
```

controller:

```
   $update_order_status = view('include.delivery_information')->render();      
    return Response::json([
        'update_order_status' => $update_order_status,
    ]);
```

Comment: what is the error, could you please include the logs?

Comment: Add the deliver_information blade

Comment: add this script once in the footer of that page

Comment: @loic.lopez im getting the error: You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page.

Comment: @AmitSharma it is the same, if I included it out of the rendering page, the google api form will never work

Comment: @lizeshakya nothing important in deliver_information, it is just google form

Comment: Isn't the error/warning _"You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page"_ pretty clear? Just include it once instead of multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because it was including the google API script multiple times

Remove `callback=initAutocomplete` from

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=0000&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" defer></script>`

and call the initAutocomplete function inside the on change of

```
<input id="autocomplete" class="addressInput-textInput s-form-control input-overflow" onClick="this.select();" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" required=""/>
```

and add the script only once in the blade other than **include.delivery_information**

Comment: first I don't know how to call initAutocomplete , but even I deleted it still get the same error message